# What causes duplicate PKs in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, archive, auto-increment

I encountered this quite a few times so far, but still don't understand it (my MySQL internals skills are equal to none).

I know it's probably a [PEBKAC](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/PEBKAC) but trying to replicate the behavior manually ends up with an error (autoincrement).

```
CREATE TABLE `foo_bar` (
  `id` int(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(12) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` int(12) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_number` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` longtext NOT NULL,
  `message_received` int(12) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `failed_to_send` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `fraudulent_activity` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=ARCHIVE DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I find this hard to believe. Primary keys, by definition are unique and shouldn't even allow NULL values. If MySQL allows this, I doubt that anybody would consider MySQL for anything serious.

Comment: Can you post your create table script?

Comment: I'm assuming the table has multiple PKs. If a table has two PKs then it will create a string of the two column values, joined. And then the uniqueness is based on that value. So if you had a PK on `x` and `y` you could have `x -> 1, y -> 1` and `x -> 1, y -> 2` but it will fail if you try `x -> 1, y -> 1` again (same goes for `y`).

Comment: @Icarus is there maybe a way to force the query to execute regardless of errors? Maybe ARCHIVE dbs are different from the other (as they don't seem to have actual indexes)?

Comment: @Kemo then the issue is not really that MySQL is allowing duplicate PKs, the issue is that the database you are looking at doesn't have a primary key defined, perhaps because, as you mentioned, it's used for archiving purposes and it doesn't need this constraint.

Comment: @kemo: Can you edit your question by adding the table's definition?

Comment: @Icarus yeah but still the field is autoincremented and trying to abuse it manually fails.. I'll try to google it up some more and post any solutions here.

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` does not necessarily mean a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` key. Does the table have a Primary or Unique Key?

Comment: @marshall: What you are referring to, are not called mutilple PKs. But compound (or sometimes compoiste) PKs. A table can have only one PK.

Comment: @Kemo: So, `SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM foo_bar GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*)>1` return rows? This is strange indeed.

Comment: @ypercube not only strange but I would have to "see to believe," as my blind uncle used to say...

Comment: @ypercube yes, there was one field that could be counted twice before I hit REPAIR TABLE. Another strange thing is that it never produced any errors except after dumping and trying to import it from that dump elsewhere.

Comment: Not sure how Archive engine works and how this happened. But I guess you can answer (and accept) that Repair Table solves the issue.

Comment: Are you sure the problem was not in importing? (the target table is different, has more indexes than the `id` Primary key)?

Comment: @ypercube right. I was trying to explain it in a way that is easy to understand. Hence why I explained how it creates that compound. And not all UIs make it clear that it's a compound, when it looks like you can assign a PK to multiple columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answer to "what caused this" didn't come up, `REPAIR TABLE` fixes the problem.

Answering this so I can close the question.

Answer (score 0):

When your program inserts a row in the database, it should provide NULL as the value for auto-incremented field:

```
CREATE TABLE  `customers` (
    `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `name` VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;


INSERT INTO  `customers` ( `id` , `name` )
VALUES ( NULL ,  'Customer 1' ), ( NULL ,  'Customer 2' );
```

If you try to insert a specific value in `id` field, MySQL will give an error:

```
SQL query: 

    INSERT INTO  `customers` ( `id` , `name` )
    VALUES ( '1',  'Customer 3' );

MySQL said: 
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: Thanks but I already said that trying to replicate the behavior manually ends up with an error :)